What is the formula of the series sum for the series $1,1,2,1,2,3,1,2,3,4........1,2,3,4......n$
So, I am looking for the series sum formula of the series $$1,1,2,1,2,3,1,2,3,4........1,2.....n$$
Like there are $n$ number of sequences in this series where each sequence has one extra term that is 1 greater than the last term of the previous sequence.
I have been trying this problem for a while now and have come up with a formula that proceeds as follows:
$$2[\{2n+(n/2 -1)*n\}n/4 -(2+6+12.....+n^2/4 -n/2)]$$
As I continue like this the problem gets even more complicated. Help and guidance would be deeply appreciated.

Please use MathJax. Here is a
tutorial.

Each sub-sequence of the form $1,2,\ldots,r$ has sum $\frac12r(r+1)$; and there are $n$ of these. So the total sum is
$$\sum_{r=1}^n\tfrac12r(r+1)=\frac12\left(\sum_{r=1}^nr^2+\sum_{r=1}^nr\right)$$
The standard formulas for these can be found here for the first sum, and here for the second sum.
(As the commenters point out, this simplifies to a nice tidy expression!)

Actually it is not necessary to split, $\sum r=\frac 12n(n+1)$ and $\sum r(r+1)=\frac 13n(n+1)(n+2)$ and this pattern is general $\sum r(r+1)(r+2)=\frac 14n(n+1)(n+2)(n+3)$; etc...

Isn't the result $$\sum\limits_{r=1}^n \left(\sum\limits_{k=1}^r k\right)=\frac{1}{6} n (n+1) (n+2)?$$

@StevenClark it is, $\frac 12\times\frac 13=\frac 16$, if you do recursive summation all $\frac 1n$ factors will combine into one $\frac 1{n!}$ factor.
